# Conditional filter function

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem with my filter function. I have a data structure as shown in the image below.

[image: bridals array]

As you can see, I have an array of objects named **bridals** and it keeps another array of objects named **plans**. So inside that I am trying to filter **people**.

Here is the filter function.

```
export function peopleFilter(bridals, people){
    if (people.length === 0) {
        return bridals;
    } else {
        bridals.forEach(bridal => {
            bridal.plans.filter((item) => {
                if (item.people === people) {
                    return bridals;
                }   
            })
        })

        return bridals;            
    }
}
```

The function `peopleFilter()` should *filter* **plans** with selected value only and *return* with **bridals**, but it returns nothing. No error is shown as well.

So I tried something like below.

```
bridals.forEach(bridal => {
    bridal.plans.slice().reverse().forEach((item, index, object) => {
        if (item.people !== people) {
            bridal.plans.splice(object.length - 1 - index, 1)                    
        }
    })
})

return bridals;
```

This above code is doing what I want. But there is one problem. So in the end when I select no value, it should display all plans. But it doesn't because I already removed the plans using `splice()` every time I select some value.

So I am stuck about this. How can I fix it?

Comment: The number of people would actually be found at `bridals[i].plans[n].people`. So you want an outer loop on bridals with an inner loop on plans. Yes, that's a loop within a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it might be easier to iterate over your bridal array with a map. Within the map, filter plans for each bridal, then return a new obj, which can be accomplished with spread syntax.

```
    const filterFunc = (bridals, people) => {
        return bridals.map(bridal => {
            const filteredPlans = bridal.plans.filter(plan => plan.people === people);
            return { ...bridal, plans: filteredPlans };
       })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is worked out. could please explain this part "`return { ...bridal, plans: filteredPlans };"`

Comment: certainly...this is using spread syntax, which effectively allows you to create a shallow copy of an object(s) properties in a new object literal. For example, if you had obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 }, obj2 = { c: 3 }, and obj3 = { ...obj1, ...obj2 } then obj3 would be { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } (effectively merging the objs). Notably, especially for this example, when using the spread sytax, later spread properties that are the same overwrite earlier ones (with shallow effect). So if  obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 } and obj2 = { b: 3 }, and obj3 = { ...obj1, ...obj2 } then obj3 would be { a: 1, b: 3 }.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to know the people count for all bridals and plans:

```
var total = 0;
bridals.forEach(function(b){
  b.plans.forEach(function(o){
    total += o.people;
  });
});
```

Of course, I can't really tell what you're trying to do. I could write an entire API for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a boolean value inside the `filter()` instead of `return bridals;`. Additionally, this returned array needs to be reassigned to `bridal` array as well.

```
export function peopleFilter(bridals, people) {
  if (people.length === 0) {
    return bridals;
  } else {
    bridals.forEach(bridal => {
      bridal = bridal.plans.filter((item) => {
        return item.people === people;
      })
    })

    return bridals;
  }
}
```